# Something Diophantine

Tags: prime-numbers, nt.number-theory

Hi there,
recently I came across the following divisibility question, and I wondered if much
can be said about it.
 Let $p$ and $q$ be different primes, and suppose $p^n + q^r$ divides $p^{2m} - 1$, where
$n$, $m$, $r$ are positive integers, $n$ divides $m$, and $q^r > p^m$. Is a classification of the triples $(n,m,r)$ within reach ?
 Thanks !

Comment: Can you prove that there are infinitely many such triples?  The conditions you require are loose enough that it certainly seems like there should be, but I can't think of a proof or come up with an algorithm to generate them.

Comment: There are readily available tabulations of factorizations of numbers of the form $a^t-1$. Might be a good idea to go through those looking for divisors of the desired form to get some idea of what your triples look like. 